# Arranging Form Fields in Google Colab

Tags: python, forms, google-colaboratory

How can I arrange form fields side by side in Google Colab?

```
Marker_Color = "Red" #@param ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black", "Yelow", "Purple", "Orange"]
Marker_Size = 961 #@param {type:"slider", min:1, max:1000, step:1}
Display_Coordinates = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
Add_Legend = False #@param {type:"boolean"}
Add_More_Markers = False #@param {type:"boolean"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arranging form fields isn't supported. I'd suggest [creating a feature request](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues) on GitHub.